# Locking field properties so Docusign Sender Users are unable to modify settings

Tags: docusignapi

My company is using the Docusign integration with Salesforce and we are going to have multiple team members sending the same template via Salesforce. Once the template is sent out, the recipient is asked to revise any field with inaccurate data.

The Docusign template has been created with fields assigned to a signer role. The fields in the template are not shared, so when the template is opened by another team member they will not see the fields in their sidebar; instead, they will only see the default Docusign fields (such as signature, signer attachments, full name, etc)

My question, though:
Has anyone else tried to find a way to lock the fields on the template so the properties can not be accessed or changed, however, at the same time keep the field value editable by the sender and recipient?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved: Click the "lock" checkbox under "Template Tag Attributes" in the field settings when placing them in the template.