# How to update recipients of already sent DocuSign envelope?

Tags: java, docusignapi

How can we update the recipient email of already sent envelope?

I tried 3 methods but nothing worked

- envelopesApi.update(docuSignAccountId,envId,envelope);
- RecipientsUpdateSummary recipientsUpdateSummary = envelopesApi.updateRecipients(docuSignAccountId, envId,       recipients);

  updateRecipientsOptions.setResendEnvelope("false");
- RecipientsUpdateSummary recipientsUpdateSummary = envelopesApi.updateRecipients(docuSignAccountId, envId, recipients, updateRecipientsOptions);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and let me know any

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

// pass the docuSign account ID and envelope ID
String docuSignAccountId = "your_account_id";
String envelopeId = "your_envelope_id";
        Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
        envelope.setEmailSubject("Updated Subject"); //you can alsoUpdate the email subject
         
    envelope.getRecipients().getSigners().get(0).setEmail("new_xyz_recipient_email@example.com");   // <-- here update the recipient email
        
        // update the envelope using the EnvelopesApi
        RecipientsUpdateSummary recipientsUpdateSummary = envelopesApi.updateRecipients(docuSignAccountId, envelopeId, envelope.getRecipients());
        
        // let the if else heandel error
        if (recipientsUpdateSummary.getRecipientUpdateResults().get(0).getErrorDetails() != null) {
          
        } else {
            //email updated successfully
        }
```

Comment: Already tried this approach but gives below error -
errorDetails: class ErrorDetails {
            errorCode: RECIPIENT_UPDATE_FAILED
            message: The recipient could not be updated.  The following properties are locked and cannot be updated: Email

Comment: i believe the your origination or admin has locked property  and that is coming in the way so see [locking-field-properties-so-docusign-sender-users-are-unable-to-modify-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870075/locking-field-properties-so-docusign-sender-users-are-unable-to-modify-settings) and [dsdev-common-api-tasks-locking-and-unlocking-envelopes](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-locking-and-unlocking-envelopes)

Comment: locking-field-properties-so-docusign-sender-users-are-unable-to-modify-settings  - this says about Docusign integration with Salesforce , we have java application.
dsdev-common-api-tasks-locking-and-unlocking-envelopes - my envelope is not locked.

Comment: the above solution works but we have to update the docusign template level settings also. Thanks for the solution.